# What metrics must i use in my data(unstructured) preprocessing research?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, topic-models, metric

am currently working on preprocessing unstructured data (emails,logs,bug reports and irc chats).

i wish to prove preprocessing improves the content quality.

are there metrics available to prove this? that is to compare the raw data and the preprocessed data and show some quality improvement in numbers.

content quality - i mean to say that the preprocessed corpus is more suitable for mining with topic models than the raw one.

I am aware of perplexity. i dont want to use this metric as it only evaluates the topic model performance and not the corpus.Also i wish to evaluate the corpus quality even before the topic model is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the corpus quality even before applying topic modelling is the easy part: Select (randomly, in a balanced way) some texts (or text snippets) from your corpus and correct them manually. The amount of manual corrections needed is a good measure for your corpus quality.

Compare the preprocessed data to your manually corrected ones and look how much correction are needed after preprocessing.

It is much harder to evaluate the quality of a topic model and AFAIK there is no general consensus of Best Practices here yet.

Comment: This is sort of a manual approach...are there any statistically methods available which computes content quality by considering the individual words present in the corpus...

Comment: You can compare your corpus to a lexical resource (dictionary or wordnet) and count "out-of-dictionary" words. This is, of course, a rather rough estimate, because all dictionaries are necessarily incomplete.